# when calling the GetObjectTagging operation: Access Denied

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I'm trying to add tags to objects added in S3 for a particular Prefix.

```
{
  "Records": [
      .......... JUNK METADATA ..........
      "s3": {
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "configurationId": "#####",
        "bucket": {
          "name": "testlambdatagging",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "#######"
          },
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::testlambdatagging"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "PREFIX/starshipBlack.png",
          "size": 512822,
          "eTag": "#########",
          "sequencer": "#########"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So ideally, when I add "starshipBlack.png" @ `testlambdatagging/PREFIX` in S3; the lambda function will be triggered and the tags for this file will be added.

But the problem is that I keep getting the following error when the lambda is triggered:
`An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObjectTagging operation: Access Denied`

The code is failing at `s3_cl.get_object_tagging`

My code looks like this:

```
import boto3
import json


s3_cl = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    try:

        bucket_name = event["Records"][0]["s3"]["bucket"]["name"]
        bucket_object = event["Records"][0]["s3"]["object"]["key"]
        object_tags = s3_cl.get_object_tagging(
                    Bucket=bucket_name,
                     Key=bucket_object,
                 )
        new_key = "newKey2"
        new_value = "newValue2"
        new_dict = {'Key' : new_key, 'Value' : new_value}
        old_tags = object_tags['TagSet']
        new_tags = old_tags
        new_tags.append(new_dict)
        put_tags_response = s3_cl.put_object_tagging(
                    Bucket=bucket_name,
                    Key=bucket_object,    
                    Tagging={
                        'TagSet': new_tags
                    }
                )
        return
    except Exception as e:

        print(e)
        raise e
    return
```

My IAM Policy for the bucket is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::testlambdatagging/PREFIX",
                "arn:aws:s3:::testlambdatagging/PREFIX/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Can someone please help me understand what am I missing?
I've read multiple solutions which say that I need to add `"s3:GetObjectTagging"` to my IAM Policy which I have added.

Comment: Can you double check the IAM policy is attached to the Lambda role, NOT your personal IAM user?

Comment: This is the policy attached to the Lambda.

Comment: Try adding `arn:aws:s3:::testlambdatagging` to the resource array as well and see what happens.

Comment: It's working for `arn:aws:s3:::testlambdatagging`
@jellycsc

Comment: Weird, it shouldn't have an impact. Did you confirm the key exists?

Comment: I agree it's weird. Yup, the key exists.